# How can I know in the Android code what are the values of the parameters from build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my `build.gradle`, I have two build types:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

In the entry point of my Android project, which is `MainApplication.create()`, I am instantiating a class `ApplicationComponent`.

I have extended the class `ApplicationComponent` with a class `DebugApplicationComponent` that has some extra methods.

I would like that in case `debuggable` is `true`, `MainApplication.create()` should instantiate `DebugApplicationComponent` instead of `ApplicationComponent`.

But how can I know in `MainApplication.create()` that `debuggable` is true?

If I `Cmd-click` on `debuggable`, I get to a class called `DefaultBuildType`. I'm not sure what this class is or how to reference it from `MainApplication`.

Comment: FYI there's no need to specify `debuggable` for debug and release build types as that is the default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
   //Do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own variables in your `app/build.gradle` configuration file.

```
  buildTypes {
          debug {
              debuggable true
              buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG_REQUIRED", "true"
          }

          release {
              debuggable false
              buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG_REQUIRED", "false"
          }
  }
```

And use it like this `BuilConfig.LOG_REQUIRED`